# Formatting Divs for MVC - how to?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, html

If I am making a page using only the DIV elements - how would I go about aligning it to something shown in the picture below? What is the best approach (besides trial and error :)

I am not experienced in css and if you answer contains usage of this please provide brief explanation.

[image]

Bonus: How can I easily make the first column right-aligned as well?

Comment: please provide your HTML markup for an accurate answer.

Comment: @ace: what do you mean? If you are wondering about the image, it not done in the markup - it just excel baby :)     hence my need to ask it on the wonderful SO.

Comment: is this really an MVC question? seems like simple HTML/CSS to me. ok i guess you need to know how to apply CSS to MVC controls, but it's simple: `Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class="foo" }`.

Comment: and also, i hate to say it - but that form seems better suited to a table than a div. it's `tabular` data.

Comment: @VoodooChild: i added the text-align: right to the css i provided below. it should work. You can pretty it up further.

Comment: @VoodooChild : I don't understand your comment about image /markup/ excel baby... What i'm asking in my original comment is that if you want a css solution, then you need to provide HTML code that you have, without that you can not correctly apply css. But i've given you a generic solution which should work.

Comment: @RPM1984: I rather use tables as well, however for this example I would rather only use divs. They are suppose to be better to use.

Comment: @ace: thanks for your solution I am looking at it at the moment. My other comment was saying that there is no HTML code for the image above. I created that image in MS Excel

Comment: @RPM1984: any idea how I would pass the css class down to the controller in the Html.ActionLink(...)?

Comment: @VoodooChild - try this: **`Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = 1 } // route args, new { @class = "foo" })`**

Comment: @RPM1984: Thanks for verifying it. I have another question and if you can post it below as an answer please. In order to use this css class at the view, I have to do it like:   `<div class="field" > <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address, new { @class="foo" })%> </div>`  ---this applies the `field` style to the MVC control, but how can I add this style to the `div` instead?

Comment: Not really sure why you want to pass the class to the controller - i would be hardcoding it in the markup. CSS is not a concern of the controller. Nonetheless, if you have put the class in the ViewModel, just do **`<div class="<%: Model.SomePropertyofModelWhichHasCssClass %>">`**

Comment: @RPM1984: If I don't pass the class down to the controller, how else would my ViewModel have access to it? Where can I define the `<link..` for the css in? Right now I have it in Site.Master - should it not go there?

Comment: @VoodooChild - sorry, im really confused as to what your trying to do here. Unless im missing something, you are trying to style a form, which you can do with @ace's solution below - just apply the class directly in the markup (`<div class="field">`). Your master has `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="<%: Url.Content('/Content/Site.css')"%>` and your View makes use of that CSS. "Why do you need to pass it to the controller? It's not part of the model.

Comment: Sry I am not very familiar with css set-up. After your last comment I just added the new css in the site.css and I could use it in the View directly. Thanks. But the formatting is still off for the second columns I am hardcoding the padding for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you will generally go about it, given the following markup :

```
   HTML :

    <div class="label">Name</div>
    <div class="field"><input type="text" name="xxx"></div>

    CSS:

    .label
    {
      float:left;
      clear: left;
      text-align:right;
    }

    .field
    {
        float:left   
        padding-left:10px;
     }
```

Basically add the label class to the first div, and field class to the second. and then repeat the pattern for each of your fields in the form.

Edit:
For 3 Columns:

```
<div class="label">Name</div>
<div class="field"><input type="text" name="xxx"></div>
<div class="field">Help Text  ...blah blah blah</div>
```

Just apply class field to any divs you want to appear in the same line. Apply class label to any div you want to start in a new line.

Comment: i updated my answer for 3 columns, please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: This doesn't work. The alignment for the second column isn't correct. The second column starts right after the labels - I want something similar to what is in the image in the questing.

Comment: if you want space, add padding-left to .field class, see my edited answer above.

Comment: also add <%=Html.TextBox(...)%> for the inputs

Comment: hmmm...doesn't work. Actually I am applying it to the DIVs but these divs have `Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)` nested inside - should I be applying the style to these MVC controls instead?

Comment: Please show the HTML markup that is generated, only then can we correctly apply the css styles.